# Given $P(B)=0.7$ $P(A|B')=0.4$ and $P(A'|B)=0.6$. Find $P(A\cap B)$

Tags: probability

Given $P(B)=0.7$ $P(A|B')=0.4$ and $P(A'|B)=0.6$. Find $P(A\cap B)$

**My Working:**

Since $P(A'|B)=\frac{P(A'\cap B)}{P(B)}$ $\Rightarrow$ $P(A'\cap B)=0.7*0.6$. To be honest I have tried different methods, but kind find a way to approach a formula or any equation that gives me value of $P(A\cap B)$. Kindly guide me.

Comment: How did you get $P(A'\cap B)=0.7\times 0.6$ --- are you thinking $P(B)=0.7$ which is not given?  Instead, you have 4 unknowns $P(A\cap B), P(A\cap B'), P(A'\cap B), P(A'\cap B')$ and 4 equations so solve them.

Comment: Yes $P(B)=0.7$. I have typo. I have fixed it

Comment: Title still says P(A)=0.7

Comment: It's fixed now :D

Comment: Can you see why $P(A\mid B)=0.4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got $P(A'\cap B)=0.42$

On Venn diagram, you would realise $A'\cap B=B-A=B-(A\cap B)$

So, $P(A'\cap B)=P(B)-P(A\cap B)\implies P(A\cap B)=P(B)-P(A'\cap B)=0.7-0.42=0.28$

**Method $2$:**

$$P(A'|B)=1-P(A|B)$$$$\implies P(A|B)=1-0.6=0.4$$$$\implies \dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=0.4$$$$\implies P(A\cap B)=0.4*0.7=0.28$$

Answer (score 1):

$$P(A\cap B)=P(A\mid B)P(B)=(1-P(A^c\mid B))P(B)=(1-0.6)0.7=0.28$$